# If Statement in Elixir/Gulp

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

```
elixir(function(mix) {

  mix
 .sass(['app.scss'])
 ...
 //if statement .uglify()
```

How can I have an if statement in my elixir file, I wish to check

```
 if (elixir.config.production)
```

and then perform uglify if true.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running `$ gulp --production` right before you deploy your app. That way your production files will be minified.

Alternately, you could define two different tasks, one for local and one for production:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp'),
elixir              = require('laravel-elixir');

gulp.task('default', function() {
});

gulp.task('local-elixir', function() {
    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix
        .sass('styles.scss', 'public/css')
        //etc
});

gulp.task('production-elixir', function() {
    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix
        .sass('styles.scss', 'public/css')
        .uglify()
        //etc
});
```

Note these are just quick examples and the code most likely won't work "out of the box"